# How to stop the program if the IF statement is true in VB?

Tags: vb.net

So is there any way to stop executing or resuming the program if an IF statement is true? I mean for the program to not resuming the rest of the codes?

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim name As String = ""
        Dim phoneNum As String = ""
        Dim dblCpu As Double
        Dim dblRam As Double
        Dim dblMotherboard As Double
        Dim dblStorage As Double
        Dim dblGpu As Double
        Dim dblPcCase As Double
        Dim dblPsu As Double
        Dim price As Double
        Dim tax As Double
        Dim total As Double
        Const service As Double = 150

        input(name, phoneNum, dblCpu, dblRam, dblMotherboard, dblStorage, dblGpu, dblPcCase, dblPsu)
        price = calculatePrice(dblCpu, dblRam, dblMotherboard, dblStorage, dblGpu, dblPcCase, dblPsu)
        tax = calculateTax(price)
        total = calculateTotal(price, tax, service)
        output(price, service, tax, total)
    End Sub
Sub input(ByRef name As String, ByRef phoneNum As String, ByRef dblCpu As Double, ByRef dblRam As Double,
              ByRef dblMotherboard As Double, ByRef dblStorage As Double, ByRef dblGpu As Double,
              ByRef dblPcCase As Double, ByRef dblPsu As Double)
        name = txtCustName.Text
        phoneNum = txtPhoneNum.Text

        If radI3.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 489
        ElseIf radI5.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 859
        ElseIf radI7.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 1399
        ElseIf radRyzen3.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 499
        ElseIf radRyzen5.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 849
        ElseIf radRyzen7.Checked = True Then
            dblCpu = 1489
        End If
        
        //a few other if statements

        If (radI3.Checked = True Or radI5.Checked = True Or radI7.Checked = True) And (radAmdAsrock.Checked = True Or radAmdGigabyte.Checked = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a motherboard that is compatible with the CPU.")
            Return
        End If
        If (radRyzen3.Checked = True Or radRyzen5.Checked = True Or radRyzen7.Checked = True) And (radIntelAsus.Checked = True Or radIntelMsi.Checked = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a motherboard that is compatible with the CPU.")
            Return
        End If

        If radI3.Checked = False And radI5.Checked = False And radI7.Checked = False And radRyzen3.Checked = False And radRyzen5.Checked = False And radRyzen7.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a CPU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radIntelAsus.Checked = False And radIntelMsi.Checked = False And radAmdAsrock.Checked = False And radAmdGigabyte.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a motherboard.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radRam8gb.Checked = False And radRam16gb.Checked = False And radRam32gb.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a RAM.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If chk120ssd.Checked = False And chk240ssd.Checked = False And chk480ssd.Checked = False And chk1tbssd.Checked = False And chk1tbhdd.Checked = False And chk2tbhdd.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a storage.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radGpu650.Checked = False And radGpu1050ti.Checked = False And radGpu1660ti.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a GPU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radCaseTecware.Checked = False And radCaseSegotep.Checked = False And radCaseGamdias.Checked = False And radCaseLianLi.Checked = False And radCaseNzxt.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a case.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radpsu450.Checked = False And radpsu550.Checked = False And radpsu650.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a PSU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
```

For example, if both radI3 and radI5 is not checked, i want the program to stop. Using "close()" and "stop" will close the program and i dont want that. Because after this segment, there are calculations and outputs. So i dont want the calculation to proceed and display an output unless the user checked one of the radio button.

Comment: This condition is checked in a method, right? So, just `Return`.

Comment: I do it in a sub procedure.

Comment: Yes, that's called a Method. Write `Return` after `MsgBox()` (you should use `MessageBox.Show()`)

Comment: It still proceeds to the main event and do the calculations outputs.

Comment: Well, then try to give some context to this code. When it's run, *where* it's run etc. -- Did you see the MessageBox pop? If you `Return`, *where* do you return to (that's part of the *context*)?

Comment: At first, when it runs, it will go to a sub procedure named input() which contains the if statements above and some calculations. When it returns, it still do the calculations. I realize that the if statements are below the calculations, so it will execute the calculations first. So i switch the positions of the if statements to the top of the method input(). Then there was no calculations made but the output is still displayed. The only way that i can make it works is by moving the if statements at the top of the main events. And yes using `return`.

Comment: You need to post your code, not *describe* it in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67471945/edit) your question and add the missing details (you can find the `Edit` link right below the question's body).

Comment: `If radI3.Checked = False And radI5.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must at least select a CPU.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) Return
End If`

Answer (score -1):

Update: After reading the comment, someone suggested to use Return like above. But it still execute the calculation(method price, tax, total). Then i moved all the if statement for validation inside the main event and it worked. It looked like this.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim name As String = ""
        Dim phoneNum As String = ""
        Dim dblCpu As Double
        Dim dblRam As Double
        Dim dblMotherboard As Double
        Dim dblStorage As Double
        Dim dblGpu As Double
        Dim dblPcCase As Double
        Dim dblPsu As Double
        Dim price As Double
        Dim tax As Double
        Dim total As Double
        Const service As Double = 150

        If (radI3.Checked = True Or radI5.Checked = True Or radI7.Checked = True) And (radAmdAsrock.Checked = True Or radAmdGigabyte.Checked = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a motherboard that is compatible with the CPU.")
            Return
        End If
        If (radRyzen3.Checked = True Or radRyzen5.Checked = True Or radRyzen7.Checked = True) And (radIntelAsus.Checked = True Or radIntelMsi.Checked = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a motherboard that is compatible with the CPU.")
            Return
        End If

        If radI3.Checked = False And radI5.Checked = False And radI7.Checked = False And radRyzen3.Checked = False And radRyzen5.Checked = False And radRyzen7.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a CPU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radIntelAsus.Checked = False And radIntelMsi.Checked = False And radAmdAsrock.Checked = False And radAmdGigabyte.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a motherboard.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radRam8gb.Checked = False And radRam16gb.Checked = False And radRam32gb.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a RAM.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If chk120ssd.Checked = False And chk240ssd.Checked = False And chk480ssd.Checked = False And chk1tbssd.Checked = False And chk1tbhdd.Checked = False And chk2tbhdd.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a storage.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radGpu650.Checked = False And radGpu1050ti.Checked = False And radGpu1660ti.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a GPU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radCaseTecware.Checked = False And radCaseSegotep.Checked = False And radCaseGamdias.Checked = False And radCaseLianLi.Checked = False And radCaseNzxt.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a case.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        If radpsu450.Checked = False And radpsu550.Checked = False And radpsu650.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("You must at least select a PSU.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Alert")
            Return
        End If

        input(name, phoneNum, dblCpu, dblRam, dblMotherboard, dblStorage, dblGpu, dblPcCase, dblPsu)
        price = calculatePrice(dblCpu, dblRam, dblMotherboard, dblStorage, dblGpu, dblPcCase, dblPsu)
        tax = calculateTax(price)
        total = calculateTotal(price, tax, service)
        output(price, service, tax, total)
    End Sub
```